# Conditional CSS for IE in Wordpress not working

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer, conditional-statements, stylesheet

`enter code here`I know this has been brought up so many times but I am really struggling to find the answer.

I am currently using the following code:

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
    <style type="text/css">@import "<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/ie.css";</style>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <style type="text/css">@import "<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/ie8.css";</style>
<![endif]-->
```

However, the first stylesheet does not pick up at all and the IE8 one is only picked up in IE9. 
I really don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

Using strict XHTML. Any help would be massively appreciated.

Oh and also yes, my main reset and other stylesheet is above these. Also I am using Wordpress - this shouldn't make a difference.

**EDIT:**

Here is some more detail

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-    strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> <?php wp_title(); ?></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/reset.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" />
        <!--[if IE 9]>
        <link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/ie.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <![endif]-->
        <!--[if IE 8]>
        <link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/ie8.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <![endif]-->
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Averia+Serif+Libre:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
```

I then write some JavaScript in the head and call in Jquery. nothing out of the ordinary.

Comment: please provide some more context, it seems fine (syntax-wise).

Comment: you should also avoid the `@import` declaration style, as IE reads it after all other page content has loaded. try and inject the file path into a `link`'s `href` attribute instead.

Comment: Did you check whether your IE works in quirks mode?

Answer (score 1):

assuming these are located in the document `head`, try and replace them with:

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
    <link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/ie.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/ie8.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: no need to be sorry. please provide more information regarding the problem, so we can help.

Comment: OK - so now I have this

`<!--[if IE 9]> 
    <link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/ie.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
<![endif]-->`

This works! However, it is picked up in all versions of IE and not just IE 9.

The bad news is the IE 8 one doesnt work. It doesn't pick anything up at all.
I've coded a whole website and I can't believe I'm finding this the hardest part :/

Thanks again!!

Comment: could you **please** edit your question to provide **more information**? it'd be easier for me and others to investigate.

Comment: anyone got any answers for me?

Comment: not sufficient information. based on the current info and code snippets provided, it cannot be determined whether there's a problem or not.